# Are gentile circumcisions a sign from God?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah

A ger tzedek friend of mine told me that he had been circumcised long before his conversion. Another question on bris milah through MY mentioned 55% of non-Jews are circumcised at birth. He mentioned that as his life gravitated to Yiddishkeit, his premature bris served as a confirmation he was on the right path.

Anyways, I'm not asking why gentiles medically or socially circumcise. Reasons known range from sexual taboos and Christian-based reasoning to hygienic and health benefits.

The discussion [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/why-does-yosef-command-the-egyptians-to-circumcise) explains why Yosef made the Egyptians do bris. I'm looking to see if there are opinions that explain why gentiles today (especially in America where there's less claim of "ancestral and cultural connection") acquire circumcision? Is it a siman for their immoral sexuality in past gilgulim? Conceptually, is it like non-jews who nurse from a Jewish woman tend to gravitate toward Judaism?

Comment: Americans are mostly circumcised. Europeans on the other hand...

Comment: Off topic as it's asking about other religions?

Comment: @Salmononius2 if I read this correctly, it's asking whether Judaism believes that the phenomenon of circumcision among gentiles is a God-given sign of something.